# How to avoid Azure build pipeline adding a tag to git branch?

Tags: azure-pipelines

When running a Azure build pipeline there is a step called `Label sources` and it adds a git tag to branch. How to avoid this? Is there any option to disable this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go Get Source, and enable **Never** under **Tag source**:

[image]

This is used to tag the source file while build running. If you want to disable it, just enable **Never** tag source.